# Why custom services do not work on cron jobs in strapi.io

Tags: cron, strapi

I created a cron job and use Strapi custom service that I wrote. But an error comes as: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'services' of undefined at Job.1 * * * * * [as job]` .

Here is my cron job code:

```
module.exports = {
  
  '1 * * * * *': ({ strapi }) => {
    strapi.services.account.myService();
  },
};
```

I'm using strapi version 3.6.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is simple. You're using the syntax from `StrapiV4` in `StrapiV3`. The correct syntax for cronjob in strapiv3 is as follows:

```js
module.exports = {
  /**
   * Simple example.
   * Every monday at 1am.
   */

  '0 0 1 * * 1': () => {
    // you can then reference you strapi custom service like so
    await strapi.services.account.myServiceMethod();
  },
};
```

###### References

- [Cron Jobs in Strapi V4](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/configurations/optional/cronjobs.html#cron-jobs)
- [Cron Job in Strapi V3](https://docs-v3.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/configurations.html#cron-tasks)